# Sum function of values per line which are located in many columns with the same name

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2010

Please could you help me with this Excel function which should sum all values in columns and lines?

I have these basic data:

```
  column  100    100     200     300      100     200     300      200       100
Row
A          1       2      5       10      1        3        7       10       12
D          2       3      6       11      2        4        8       11       13
B          5       4      1        5      4        2        4        5        4
E          4       5      8       13      4        6       10       13       15
A          4       3      0        4      3        1        3        4        3
F          5       4      1        5      4        2        4        5        4
D          1       7      5        1     12        2       13        3       14
F          2       8      6        2     13        3       14        4       15
E          4       4      1        4      4        5        5        6        6
E          4      10      8        4     15        5       16        6       17
A          3       3      0        3      3        4        4        5        5
C          4       4      1        4      4        5        5        6        6
D          4       5      8       13      3        6       11        8       11
A          4       5      8        2      4        8        4        5        4
```

I need to get the sum of the same rows/lines like this.

```
Sum 100 200 300                     
A   ?   ?   ?                       
B   ?   ?   ?                       
C   ?   ?   ?                       
D   ?   ?   ?                       
E   ?   ?   ?                       
F   ?   ?   ?
```

There could be more columns added (400-xxx) and lines added (G-xxx).

I know that this is good for pivot tables but I cannot use them - I need some function.

Any help, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function called `SUMPRODUCT` here:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$J$15)*($A$2:$A$15=$A18)*($B$1:$J$1=B$17))
            ^----------^ ^---------------^ ^--------------^
                  1              2                3
```

1. This is the range of the values to be summed up.
2. This is to get only the parts matching the letter.
3. This is to get only the parts matching the headers.

Multiply them all together and you end up with an array containing 0s and all the values you need to sum up. `SUMPRODUCT` then adds them altogether.

[image]